# vba code to visible Or Hidde sheets without activate Them

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Please to visible Or Hidde sheets without activate Them!
I don't want the code in the `Worksheet_Activate` Or `Worksheet_Change` event to be executed!
I have a lot of sheets in the file and some of them have code `Worksheet_Activate` Or `Worksheet_Change` event, that when they are visible or hidden it takes a long time to open the file by running the code.

I have written the code below which will be executed when the excel file is opened

thank you

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheet5.Select
    Sheets("User Database").Visible = xlVeryHidden
'===============================================
    Dim varSheet                    As Variant
    Dim arrVisibleSheets            As Variant
    Dim arrHiddenSheets             As Variant

    arrVisibleSheets = Array(Sheet5)
    arrHiddenSheets = Array(Sheet1, Sheet13, Sheet14, Sheet15, Sheet16, Sheet17, Sheet18, Sheet3, Sheet9) ', Sheet16
    
    For Each varSheet In arrVisibleSheets
        varSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next varSheet

    For Each varSheet In arrHiddenSheets
        varSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Next varSheet
    
    Sheet5.Select
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet5.Select
    
With Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 .ScreenUpdating = False
 .DisplayStatusBar = False
 .EnableEvents = False
End With

    Dim varSheet                    As Variant
    Dim arrVisibleSheets            As Variant
    Dim arrHiddenSheets             As Variant

    arrVisibleSheets = Array(Sheet5)
    arrHiddenSheets = Array(Sheet1, Sheet13, Sheet14, Sheet15, Sheet16, Sheet17, Sheet18, Sheet3, Sheet9)  ', Sheet16

    For Each varSheet In arrVisibleSheets
        varSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next varSheet

    For Each varSheet In arrHiddenSheets
    If varSheet.Visible = True Then varSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Next varSheet
    
    If Application.Windows.Count > 1 Then 'more than one workbook open: Hide workbook only
        Application.Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False
    Else 'only one workbook open: Hide application
        Application.Visible = False
    End If
    Sheets("User Database").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    
With Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 .ScreenUpdating = True
 .DisplayStatusBar = True
 .EnableEvents = True
End With

A_Login_Form.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like you already know about using `EnableEvents` ?

Comment: Yes!
but not working! Worksheet_Change event code runing still

Comment: @AllahiarArianfar then find out what's triggerin it and then make sure you'll disable events before running said part

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII I have connections, pivot tables, and external links in the file.
Can these have an effect?
Of course, I set that they are not refreshed when the file is opened.

Comment: Set a breakPoint at the start of your programm and step through it with F8, then you should be able to see which part(s) trigger(s) the events

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII thank You. When the program is open, the breakpoint works well and without interruption, and even without the breakpoint, the codes run very quickly and without interruption. But when I close the program and open it again, I have a problem when the file opens.
Breakpoint also does not work when the file is closed and opened.

Comment: You don't disable events when closing the file? (in `Workbook_BeforeClose`)

Comment: @TimWilliams i ckeck it again. no i don't disable events when closing the file?

Comment: Have you tried doing that?

Comment: @TimWilliams i test it now, i add  **Application.EnableEvents = False** in **Workbook_BeforeClose** event but did not solve.

Comment: In `Workbook_Open` you call `Sheet5.Select` before disabling events

Comment: @TimWilliams sheet5 is always visible. i change it and paste Sheet5.Select after disabling events. not solve

Answer (score 0):

In your Sub Workbook_Open(), why do you select a sheet at the beginning of your code (Sheet5.Select)? Usually this instruction should be at the end of your Sub.

Comment: Hello. sheet5 always visible and I select it before , so as not to receive an error! Of course, this does not cause an error

Answer (score 0):

I am very grateful to all those who guided me.
The problem was that in my userform(A_Login_Form.Show)!
**showmodal = false**, I set it (A_Login_Form.Show) **showmodal = true** and it was fixed.
thank you.